# Show active state on menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want the menu on my site to have a specific CSS style depending on which page I'm on.
[screenshot with an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw9gl.png)

I have created jQuery file that I connected to all HTML pages:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.header-nav a').each(function(){
        if(document.location.href == this.href){
            $(this).addClass('header-nav__item__active');
        }
    });
});
```

I also added a certain style of the active menu state to the style file:

```
.header-nav__item__active {
    color: rgb(48, 165, 204);
}
```

When I switch between pages, everything works, but when I first open the site, the main page is not active.

Comment: Have you tried logging `document.location.href` and `this.href` on the home page?

Comment: This might have to do with: [Understanding the Index.html Page on a Website](https://www.thoughtco.com/index-html-page-3466505).

Comment: Please tag correctly. Javascript means vanilla javascript. Your code indicates the usage of jQuery, not Javascript.

Comment: @tacoshy yes, I did miss that, thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
var currentLocation = window.location.href;

$('.header-nav a').each(function() {
    // Use indexOf to check if the currentLocation contains the href
    if (currentLocation.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) {
        $(this).addClass('header-nav__item__active');
    }
});
```